# how to identify cross login in azure synapse analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-data-warehouse

In my environment user are logged in to SQL server via MFA authentication with their email id.
Its possible for single user to log in to multiple laptops with same credentials.

Can we track user login details machine specific ??

Application name : SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO
AUTHENTICATION : MULTI FACTOR AUTHENTICATION